# How to Post Data from HTML Table in Classic ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic

I'm trying to post some field data from my HTML table to a new page, but I can't seem to get my hidden input value to be anything other than null.  Every row in the table has a Details button that I want to post just the primary key from that table to the posted page.  Here's what I've tried that doesn't work:

```
<tr VALIGN="top">
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Details" /> 
        <input type= "hidden" name = "post" value=<%rs.Fields(1).Name%>/>
    </td>
<% For I = 0 to rs.fields.count - 1 %>
<td BORDERCOLOR="#c0c0c0"><font SIZE="1" FACE="Arial" COLOR="#000000"><%=(rs.Fields(I).Value) & "&nbsp;"%><br></font>
</td>
<%next%>
```

I've also tried a few other variations, but I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, I couldn't figure it out.  If you need more info let me know, thanks

EDIT:

`rs.Fields(1).Name` has a value when I do Response.Write directly above the posted code, so I know that the result is not null.

Comment: If the output (rs.Fields(I).Value) does not have a value, then there is likely an issue with your query. What does your actual HTML output look like?

Comment: When I do a "Response.Write" of rs.Fields(1).Name it correctly prints the name.  Here is the line of HTML when I inspect it in the browser:
<input type="hidden" name="post" value="/"/>

Comment: But does it work with a .value?

Comment: Yes it does work with .value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the Response.Write or in a short form <%= %>
(You still need to output the value to the HTML!)

```
<input type= "hidden" name = "post" value="<%= rs.Fields(1).Name %>" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it will be affecting it, but try it without the spaces around the "=":

```
<input type="hidden" name="post" value=<%rs.Fields(1).Name%> />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still the same output though.

Comment: @PhilipDevine it is because "value=<%rs.Fields(1).Name%>" must be like value="<%=rs.Fields(1).Name%>". Do not forget quotes around it especially if your value have spaces in it.